# Workflow Rule and Process Builder regarding Email alert Notification

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have field Contract End Date, Suppose Contract End Date as `12/12/2021`,i have to send Email alert Notification before `3 months` , How i will send, if i put `90` `days` means month date will differ in days, suppose month contains `30,31,28` How i will calculate `3 months` before from end date, in process builder and Workflow only `hours and Days` are left

**Is there any ways to caluculate the exact date for before three months for scheduling the Email alert Notification in both process builder and Workflow rule**

> In workflow rule , add time trigger option is there for time dependent
>   workflow actions, In that Rule trigger Date denotes which date, it
>   will denote when the rule is created date or In rule criteria some
>   date Calculating it will shows that date?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do that, Suppose date is 12/12/2021. Use month function of take month value and do minus 3 i.e(-3) on month that time you will get exact same value what u want but here is one problem if month is **January, February, March** you will get **-2,-1,0** respectively in that use **case function** to get month name like if u get 0 assign 12 i.e(Dec) and if u get -1 value assign 11 i.e(Nov) and if u get -2 value assign (oct).